# whats algorithm of Exim message ID

Tags: email-headers, exim, exim4

i want know a message id in Exim how to generate.
for example : 1YSWPk-0000oX-0N

also Message id in headers

```
Message-ID: <aa1e23e76be8b95bc21718a4c4e000fc@example.com>
```

and can decode these?
and any relationship with these and other email headers?

Comment: Have you tried looking into the [source code](https://github.com/Exim/exim) for yourself?

Comment: @MarkoŽivanović : I do not have any knowledge of analyzing code and decoding.

Comment: Ok, in that case this might not be the right place for your question, as per [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) guides.

Comment: Message-id was generated in which file? please send file name and line of this.

Answer (score 4):

`Exim`'s specification part 3.4 says that

> The first six characters of the message id are the time at which the
>   message started to be received, to a granularity of one second. That
>   is, this field contains the number of seconds since the start of the
>   epoch (the normal Unix way of representing the date and time of day).
>
> After the first hyphen, the next six characters are the id of the
>   process that received the message.
>
> There are two different possibilities for the final two characters:
>
> If localhost_number is not set, this value is the fractional part of
>   the time of reception, normally in units of 1/2000 of a second, but
>   for systems that must use base 36 instead of base 62 (because of
>   case-insensitive file systems), the units are 1/1000 of a second.
>
> If localhost_number is set, it is multiplied by 200 (100) and added to
>   the fractional part of the time, which in this case is in units of
>   1/200 (1/100) of a second.

Here are the headers of message sent from my `exim` to the `gmail.com`.
Lines 19-27 are generated by my MTA/exim while all lines above are generated by `gmail` servers.

```
 1  Delivered-To: kondybas@gmail.com
 2  Received: by 10.27.143.12 with SMTP id r12csp943315wld;
 3          Tue, 3 Mar 2015 12:49:41 -0800 (PST)
 4  X-Received: by 10.180.126.69 with SMTP id mw5mr50725522wib.12.1425415780590;
 5          Tue, 03 Mar 2015 12:49:40 -0800 (PST)
 6  Return-Path: <root@domain.tld>
 7  Received: from domain.tld (relay.domain.tld. [11.22.33.44])
 8          by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id y2si3224153wjy.199.2015.03.03.12.49.40
 9          for <kondybas@gmail.com>
10          (version=TLSv1.2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
11          Tue, 03 Mar 2015 12:49:40 -0800 (PST)
12  Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of root@domain.tld designates 11.22.33.44 as permitted sender) client-ip=11.22.33.44;
13  Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
14         spf=pass (google.com: domain of root@domain.tld designates 11.22.33.44 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=root@domain.tld;
15         dkim=pass header.i=@domain.tld
16  DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=domain.tld; s=s;
17          h=Date:From:Message-Id:Subject:To; bh=g3zLYH4xKxcPrHOD18z9YfpQcnk/GaJedfustWU5uGs=;
18          b=p7JbGnGFvxdvL0UESIprvXTXq1GcQTeWZOTy3nrTOynwqHz9JEKQu+nqNU6iZtC7LxmPBbOFXjy3Qbg9vH3BLdaqivk/duFSUoYenFQgQd/iaoZ8sBP3lWXx/Uz6yIy7zH2ySOZO5M/NKfG2QqZsJ8PCChJ01mCSe6bqHfcywbrAi2ZJWws3Kt3lAGIxHkdOjhcCsljrirGCCeYc8WI8PQ==;
19  Received: from root by domain.tld with local (Exim 4.85 (FreeBSD))
20          (envelope-from <root@domain.tld>)
21          id 1YStl5-00010z-JV
22          for kondybas@gmail.com; Tue, 03 Mar 2015 22:49:39 +0200
23  To: kondybas@gmail.com
24  Subject: test
25  Message-Id: <E1YStl5-00010z-JV@domain.tld>
26  From: Charlie Root <root@domain.tld>
27  Date: Tue, 03 Mar 2015 22:49:39 +0200
```

Comment: thanks,and how generate Message-ID: <aa1e23e76be8b95bc21718a4c4e000fc@example.com>

Comment: That ID was generated by software hosted on the `example.com`. I'm not sure but it look like a MD5 hash to me.

Comment: true,this is MD5 hash,but what's varibale to MD5? timestamp? any document or code for this in Exim?

Comment: I've update my answer with real headers produced by my `exim` and - just for example - by googlemail, so you can see how they differ. Lines 2, 4 and 8 shows that MTAs other than exim can generate message's ID in unpredictable form. And you can't control that behaviour.